# Syntax error on multiple CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @comando as varchar(5000)

SET @comando = 'DTEXEC  /FILE \"" /de "pass" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EW'
SELECT @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sCadenaConexion%'
          THEN '"\"'+ str_ValorVariable +'\""' 
              ELSE str_ValorVariable + 
               CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%' 
                    THEN @v_sRutaArchivo + '.csv\""' 
                    ELSE '' 
               END 
          END + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = @idPaquete
```

I want to add another validation with another case, so I try:

```
SELECT @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sCadenaConexion%'
   + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%'
          THEN '"\"'+ str_ValorVariable +'\""' 
              ELSE str_ValorVariable + 
               CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%' 
                    THEN @v_sRutaArchivo + '.csv\""' 
                    ELSE '' 
               END 
          END + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = @idPaquete
```

I get

> incorrect syntax near "from"

What am I doing wrong? I need to add another THEN sentence if I add another `CASE`? regards

As comment of missing statement I change it to:

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT @comando = @comando + ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' + Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') + '].Value\"";' 
   + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sCadenaConexion%'  
          THEN '"\"'+ str_ValorVariable +'\""' 
          + CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%'
          THEN'"\"' +str_ValorVariable +'' 
              ELSE str_ValorVariable + 
               CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%' 
                    THEN @v_sRutaArchivo + '.csv\""' 
                    ELSE '' 
               END 
                 END
          END + ''
from [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = @idPaquete
```

but when I do a select it return `NULL` value. Why it happens?

Comment: You have three `CASE` statements and two `END` keywords.

Comment: I update my question can you take a look please? @bjones

Comment: You're probably getting null values because one or more of the columns have a null value. Anything plus `NULL` will result in `NULL`. Perhaps you need to use `ISNULL()` around the columns to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: check this [Best way to do nested case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505747/best-way-to-do-nested-case-statement-logic-in-sql-server)

Comment: I think problem is because `Case` don't have `Else` clause or it doesn't metter?@bjones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) to Concatenate several expressions together:.

I have edited your case logic since the `else` part's `case when` logic is not need.

```
SELECT @comando = CONCAT ( @comando , ' /SET "\"\Package.Variables[' , 
                           Replace(str_NombreVariable,'User::','') , '].Value\"";', 
                           CASE WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sCadenaConexion%'  
                                THEN '"\"'+ str_ValorVariable +'\""' 
                                WHEN str_NombreVariable LIKE '%v_sRutaArchivo%'
                                THEN'"\"' +str_ValorVariable +@v_sRutaArchivo+'.csv""' 
                                ELSE str_ValorVariable                 
                            END 
                        )
FROM 
     [Catalogo].[catVariablesEtl] where IdPaquete = @idPaquete
```

Do read more about `CASE` Expression [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)