# Adding CASE WHEN to WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I used the following `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE (TYPE1 = :P3_ITEM1 OR :P3_ITEM1 IS NULL)
```

to filter my query on TYPE1 and it worked fine to display the records of same TYPE1 when page item P3_ITEM1 is not null.

Now I need to add two more filters for TYPE2 and TYPE3. Normally only one page item P3_ITEM1, P3_ITEM2, or P3_ITEM3 is not null, so I need to filter on whichever on is not null.

I tried

```
WHERE (TYPE1=:P3_ITEM1 OR :P3_ITEM1 IS NULL) OR
  (TYPE2=:P3_ITEM2 OR :P3_ITEM2 IS NULL) OR
  (TYPE3=:P3_ITEM3 OR :P3_ITEM3 IS NULL)
```

but it did not work.

I tried using CASE statement in my WHERE clause but no success so far. Can anyone help?

```
WHERE CASE
WHEN (:P3_ITEM1 IS NOT NULL) THEN (TYPE1=:P3_ITEM1)
WHEN (:P3_ITEM2 IS NOT NULL) THEN (TYPE2=:P3_ITEM2)
WHEN (:P3_ITEM3 IS NOT NULL) THEN (TYPE3=:P3_ITEM3)
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: can you show how can I do that in my case?

Comment: You can probably find answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505747/best-way-to-do-nested-case-statement-logic-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `AND` to combine the various filters. Each filter will evaluate to true if the parameter for it is `NULL`, so if all three are `NULL` you will get all records, but you can fill in a any, or even all three parameters to filter out unwanted records.

```
WHERE
  (TYPE1 = :P3_ITEM1 OR :P3_ITEM1 IS NULL) AND
  (TYPE2 = :P3_ITEM2 OR :P3_ITEM2 IS NULL) AND
  (TYPE3 = :P3_ITEM3 OR :P3_ITEM3 IS NULL)
```

Comment: It worked! I do not know why I thought changing OR to AND will not work! Thank you