# How to fix Nested CASE Syntax Error "Invalid Number of Arguments" in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Im running a query in Oracle and am trying to create a new column that is defined by the nested CASE statement below. I get an error on the highlighted "Else" statement  saying "Invalid Number of Arguments".

I looked it over many times and it seems to have the correct number of arguments. Am i missing something here?

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN TRD_TYP IN ('Swaption', 'IRG Floor', 'IRG Cap') 
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN BUY_SELL = 'BUY' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_CUR 
            ELSE -CURR_NOTNL_CUR
        END
    ELSE
        CASE 
            WHEN TRD_TYP = 'IRSWAP' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_CUR                 
        END
    **ELSE**
        CASE 
            WHEN TRD_TYP = 'EQSWAP' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_UNIT
        END
    ELSE
        CASE 
            WHEN TRD_TYP = 'FUTURE' 
            THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN BUY/SELL = 'BUY' 
                    THEN CURR_NOTNL_CUR / PRC 
                    ELSE -CURR_NOTNL_CUR / PRC
                END
        END
    ELSE
        CASE 
            WHEN BUY_SELL = 'BUY' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_UNIT 
            ELSE -CURR_NOTNL_UNIT
        END
END AS UNITS_OF_UNDERLYING
FROM ACTLANN.HDG_ASST_DTLS
```

Comment: What is that `**ELSE**` (assuming that's supposed to be highlighting where the error is reported) supposed to be the `ELSE` *of*?

Comment: Yes this is where i am getting the error. But if i delete that ELSE section itself, the error moves on to the next ELSE

Comment: Yes - but what are they supposed to be doing? You have the outer `CASE` with one `WHEN` and four `ELSE`s, which isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN TRD_TYP IN ('Swaption', 'IRG Floor', 'IRG Cap')
    THEN
        CASE
            WHEN BUY_SELL = 'BUY' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_CUR 
            ELSE -CURR_NOTNL_CUR
        END
    WHEN TRD_TYP = 'IRSWAP'
    THEN CURR_NOTNL_CUR                 
    WHEN TRD_TYP = 'EQSWAP'
    THEN CURR_NOTNL_UNIT
    WHEN TRD_TYP = 'FUTURE'
    THEN
        CASE
            WHEN BUY/SELL = 'BUY' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_CUR / PRC 
            ELSE -CURR_NOTNL_CUR / PRC
        END
    ELSE
        CASE 
            WHEN BUY_SELL = 'BUY' 
            THEN CURR_NOTNL_UNIT 
            ELSE -CURR_NOTNL_UNIT
        END
END AS UNITS_OF_UNDERLYING
FROM ACTLANN.HDG_ASST_DTLS
```

Your code has multiple `ELSE` clauses against the outer `CASE` expression, and there can only be one. The first three each have an inner `CASE` which doesn't need to be there; the `WHEN ... THEN` for those can be 'promoted' to the outer expression.

Comment: I see what you mean. Its working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was referring to this when i was creating the nested Case. Perhaps i misinterpreted it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505747/best-way-to-do-nested-case-statement-logic-in-sql-server