# how do I do a nested case in mysql?

Tags: mysql

observe the following line used in a select statement

```
(case when p1 = 0 then 1 else (p2-p1)/p1 end) as delta_pct,
```

this line gives the percentage change between p1 and p2, and if p1 is 0 it returns 1 to avoid the divide by 0 error. but it gives 1 if p2 is also 0 which is incorrect. how do I modify his line to account for that case as well?

something like

```
case when p1 = 0
    case when p2 = 0
        then 0
    then 1
else (p2-p1)/p1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to do nested case statement logic in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505747/best-way-to-do-nested-case-statement-logic-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CASE` expression with more levels to cover all edge cases:

```sql
CASE WHEN p1 = 0 AND p2 = 0 THEN 0
     WHEN p1 = 0 THEN 1
     ELSE (p2 - p1) / p1 END AS percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

normally instead of nested  case you can use case expressione with several AND condition  for cover your logic
but i you really need  nested  case

but i you really need  nested  case

```
case 
when p1 = 0 THEN 
    case when p2 = 0
         then 0
         ELSE 1 
         END 
else (p2-p1)/p1
END delta_pct
```

as you can cleary see in this case  the use of composite and condition is more easy

```
CASE WHEN p1 = 0 AND p2 = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN p1 = 0 THEN 1
 ELSE (p2 - p1) / p1 END delta_pct
```